# calling javascript method with a php retrieved argument

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript method in separate js file that I want to call from a HTML page with a php argument.

```
<?php

        include "connection.php";

        $selectedpatient = $_POST['patient_dropdown'];

        $myquery = "SELECT * FROM `patient_info` patient_info.Name = '$selectedpatient' ";

        $query = mysql_query($myquery);

            if ( ! $query ) {
                echo mysql_error();
                die;
            }

            $data = array();

            for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
                $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            }

         $tempdata = json_encode($data);
    ?>

        <script> data_arrival($_tempdata); </script>
```

And I defined the source for the javascript file in the HTML header. It displays two errors:

1) Parse error in the javascript file - that's understandable as I included the javascript file in header and the file gets executed before the php actually retrieves any data.

2) data_arrival method is undefined

How can I fix this ?? I want to pass the $tempdata (after its populated by php) to data_arrival method as an argument.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `data_arrival(<?php echo $_tempdata; ?>);` there's literally a thousand of examples on SO on this topic, use search.

Comment: What you mean "javascript file is executed before PHP retrieves any data"? PHP is executed first, and only then any js, html and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all: it's PHP that's executed first, not JavaScript. It can't be the other way round in your example.
2. `data_arrival` is undefined... because either you haven't defined it at all, or because it is defined after it's called.

To pass the value from PHP to JavaScript in your case, you can use:

```
data_arrival(<?php echo $_tempdata; ?>);
```

It will generate something like:

```
data_arrival([a, b, c, d, ...]);
```

Of course, `data_arrival` function need to be defined prior to its execution.

**Edit**

And maybe it's good to use the same variable name: `$_tempdata` vs `$tempdata`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that :) But the above code is displaying the content of the tempdata on the HTML page.

Comment: I think its the error with my data_arrival method now, as was using d3.json earlier to read the json file but now as the data is being passed as an argument it is not actually doing anything. The "echo"used in the argument for data_arrival is printing everything on the screen.